# Replacing repetitive function applications with deterministic values

Tags: haskell

```
f x y z = [n | n <- z, n > x + y]

f 1 2 [3,4]
```

Would `x + y` be executed only once at first so that the successive calls  be replaced by the `value 3` instead? Is `GHC` Haskell optimized up to this job for FP brings us the virtue of referential transparency?

How to trace to prove it?

Comment: It's possible for GHC to make some optimizations like this, and you can check by compiling with `-O2` and `-ddump-simpl` to view the optimized core.  This is a messy problem though.  Instead, it's always best to assign a name to a value you only want to be computed once.  Explicit value sharing is better than implicit guessing.  For example `f x y z = let value = x + y in [n | n <- z, n > value]`.  Alternatively, you could use `filter` and get the same effect: `filter (> x + y) z`.

Comment: An alternative to `let v=... in [n | n <- z, n > v]` is `[n | let v=... , n <- z , n > v ]`. They are equivalent, so choose the style you prefer.

Answer (score 9):

I don't *think* the computed value will be reused.

The general problem with this kind of thing is, `x + y` is cheap, but you could instead have some operation there that produces an utterly *vast* result, which you probably don't want to keep in memory. Which is a wordy way of saying "this is a time/space tradeoff".

Because of this, it seems GHC tends to *not* reuse work, in case the lost space doesn't make up for the gained time.

The way to find out for sure is to ask GHC to dump Core when it compiles your code. You can then see precisely what's going to get executed. (Be prepared for it to be *very* verbose though!) Oh, and make sure you turn on optimisations! (I.e., the `-O2` flag.)

If you rephrase your function as

```
f x y z = let s = x + y in [ n | n <- z, n > s ]
```

Now `s` will *definitely* be executed only once. (I.e., once per call to `f`. Each time you call `f` it'll still recompute `s`.)

Incidentally, if you're interested in saving already-computed results for the whole function, the search term you're looking for is "memoisation".

Comment: Thanks for the term `memoisation`. Does because technical challenges outweigh perceived performance gains, GHC tends to not `memoisation` by default as you mentioned? IMHO, `memoisation` can relieve apps from boilerplate code to reuse values at some extent, and it looks rather functional than imperative.

Answer (score 6):

What will happen can depend on whether you are using ghci vs. ghc and then, if you are compiling the code, what optimization level is being used.

Here is one way to test the evaluations:

```
import Debug.Trace

f x y z = [n | n <- z, n > tx x + ty y]
  where tx = trace "x"
        ty = trace "y"

main = print $ f 1 2 [3,4]
```

With 7.8.3 I get the following results:

1. ghci: `x y x y [4]`
2. ghc (no optimization): `x y x y [4]`
3. ghc -O2: `x y [4]`

It is possible that the addition of the `trace` calls affects CSE optimization. But this does show that -O2 will hoist `x+y` out of the loop.